# How to integrate multiple users into a single user microblogging site?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, microblogging

I am very new to PHP and found a tutorial on how to build a Twitter-like microblogging site from scratch. It works great, except I have no clue how to integrate a place where other uses can sign up and use the site? It seems like it is only set up for one user.

[Tutorial I used](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-twitter-interface/index.html)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please be aware: even though that came from IBM's site, and they're pretty good about things, they've let a *worst practice* sneak in.  They're using the *to-be-deprecated* `mysql_` family of functions. You should take this opportunity to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) so you can leverage [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). If nothing else, it will help you become more familiar with PHP.

Comment: +1 yep, seems like the sign up part is missing

Answer (score 0):

So **continue reading** and you will be welcome when you have a more specific question:

- [Creating A Simple Yet Secured Login/registration With Php5](//forum.codecall.net/topic/69771-creating-a-simple-yet-secured-loginregistration-with-php5)

This is a good tutorial using PHP5 and PDO (like @Charles recommend). Avoid reading some old tutorials (IBM is a good source, but the tutorial is 3,8 years old).